# finding palindrome with specific algorithm in C

Tags: c

I need help in one of my project for the accademy.
I need to code an algorithm to find palindrome number from the six digits that the user will decide to write.
There are some limitation for me, the number needs to be 6 digits long, the code must contain function that will calculate the given number and the number needs to be in array.
I will attach my algorithem so far if someone can help me figure up why it does not working.
Thank you guys!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define N 6

int palindrome(int rev_arr[N], int arr[N]);

int palindrome(int rev_arr[N], int arr[N])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int a = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            arr[i] = rev_arr[j];
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (j = N; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            if (arr[i] == rev_arr[j])
            {
                a = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                a = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return a;
}

void main()
{
    int i = 0, arr[N], rev_arr[N], j = 0, p1 = 0, a = 0;

    printf("Please enter your six digit's number:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    p1 = palindrome(rev_arr[N],arr[N]);
        if (p1 == 1)
        {
            printf("The number is palindrome! :)\n");
        }
        else if (p1 == 0)
        {
            printf("The numbe is not palindrome! :(\n");
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe *how* it is not working?

Comment: It's not working for a number of reasons, not the least of which being you (a) don't understand how to pass arrays as function arguments, and (b) are ignoring any compiler warnings telling you as-such. Your tutorial and/or text should cover arrays extensively. Also, the double-nested `arr[i] = rev_arr[j];` make no sense, since `main()` never set any values in `rev_arr` prior to that call (assuming you fix the arguments). Finally, if you're reading a number as digit characters, `%d` isn't the way to do that. That will process as many consecutive digits as possible to form a *single* value.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding the question you don't need a `O(N^2)` solution either- you can simply simultaneously iterate from the left and right end of the string towards the middle checking that the digit is equal at each iteration.

Comment: What is "palindrome number"? Is it a number which is a palindrome? Is it some number which your have to find for a given number? What do you mean with "find palindrome number"? Do you have to check whether the given number is a plaindrome and then state whether it is or is not? "The number needs to be six digits long" That does not sound like a limitation for you, more like a guarantee, i.e. something which you can rely on. "the six digits that the user will decide to write" How does that happen? Will the user enter "123456<enter>" or "1<enter>2<enter>3<enter>4<enter>5<enter>6<enter>"?

Comment: What do you mean by "the number needs to be in array"? A single number in an array sounds weird. Do you mean "I have to store each digit of the number separatly into the entries of an array?"

Comment: How often do you  expect your user to press "<enter>"? Your programmed loop around the scanf will need six times. But you only prompt the user once and it reads like asking for a single six-digit number. I for example would type "234432<enter>". Is that what you expect? Then your program will silently wait for inout 5 times more. Is that what you mean by "not working"?

Comment: In order to improve your program try this first: Have the user enter something and then output it right back at them, "This is what you entered: ...". This is to make sure that you got your input right and that it ended up in some variable in meaningful way and that your are able to access it and use it for analysis.

Comment: Please explain, to yourself and to us, the meaning of the two arrays. What do you intend to end up inside `arr`? What do you intend to end up inside rev_arr?

Comment: When you defined what the arrays contain, explain in prose how you as a human being would recognise a palindrome number.

Comment: Looking at this code fragment, `palindrome(rev_arr[N],arr[N])`, please expalin the two paramters which end up in the function. What do you think they are? An integer value in the first parameter and another integer value in the second parameter? Two complete arrays of N integers? Two pointers, one the adress of the first array, the other the address of the second array?

Comment: After explaining what is given into the function call (see above), please explain what the function (according to your prototype `int palindrome(int rev_arr[N], int arr[N]);`) actually does expect to be given. Is it the same as what it receives?

Comment: To improve your function, first try to output the parameters it receives, to make sure that what you are processing actually is what you expect.

Comment: Concerning the use of scanf, this is often helpful: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: Side note: `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` should be before the headers included.

Comment: the prototype is useless here, since you already define the function before the first time it's used. Remove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of scanning all array len you can stop to its middle len:

```
int palindrome(int arr[N])
{
    int i = 0, end = N / 2;

    for (i = 0; i < end; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] != arr[N-i-1])
            return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Pay attention also that correct call to `palindrome` function is `palindrome(arr)` and not `palindrome(arr[N])`.

So you can check if a sequence is palindrome by doing:

```
if (palindrome(arr))
    printf("The number is palindrome! :)\n");
else
    printf("The numbe is not palindrome! :(\n");
```